Add column depending on dictionary
How can I add new column to df, which contains True or False depending on dictionary?
import pandas as pd

my_dict={
    'Group1':('Item1','Item3'),
    'Group2':('Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5'),
    'Group3':('Item1')
        }

df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Item':['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4'],
            'Group':['Group1','Group1','Group2','Group3']
               })

The result I want:
df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Item':['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4'],
            'Group':['Group1','Group1','Group2','Group3'],
            'New_col':['True','False','True','False']
               })

I tried:
df['New_col']=df['Item'].str.startswith(df['Group'].apply(lambda x: my_dict.get(x)))


But I got error:
TypeError: expected a string or tuple, not Series

The most efficient in my opinion is to rework the dictionary in python to form sets:
Direct mapping:
my_dict={
    'Group1':('Item1','Item3'),
    'Group2':('Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5'),
    'Group3':('Item1',) # this must be a tuple
        }

d = {k: set(v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}

df['New_col'] = [a in d.get(b, set()) for a, b in zip(df['Item'], df['Group'])]

Reverse mapping:
my_dict={
    'Group1':('Item1','Item3'),
    'Group2':('Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5'),
    'Group3':('Item1',) # this must be a tuple
        }

d = {}
for k, t in my_dict.items():
    for x in t:
        d.setdefault(x, set()).add(k)

df['New_col'] = [b in d.get(a, set()) for a, b in zip(df['Item'], df['Group'])]

Output:
    Item   Group  New_col
0  Item1  Group1     True
1  Item2  Group1    False
2  Item3  Group2     True
3  Item4  Group3    False

substring match
you can combine a regex step to extract the keys from the column:
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, set(v for t in my_dict.values() for v in t)))
# 'Item1|Item5|Item3|Item2|Item4'

s = df['Item'].str.extract('(%s)' % pattern, expand=False)
df['New_col'] = [a in d.get(b, set()) for a, b in zip(s, df['Group'])]

Example:
      Item   Group  New_col
0   Item1a  Group1     True
1  Item2bc  Group1    False
2   Item3a  Group2     True
3  Item4ad  Group3    False


@Евгения was anything wrong with my answer?

Here is an option with isin()
d = {k: list(v) if isinstance(v,tuple) else [v] for k,v in my_dict.items()}

df.set_index('Group').T.isin(d).T.reset_index()

Output:
    Group   Item
0  Group1   True
1  Group1  False
2  Group2   True
3  Group3  False

